# Glassfish 4.1, cant login to admin console

Tags: java, windows, glassfish, glassfish-4

since 1 day I got heavy problems with my glassfish server running on windows server 2008. Everything went well, application was running smooth. But since like 1 the applications was acting weird. After a restart of the domain didnt changed anything I tried to login into the admin console. Somehow I wasnt able to login ("Authentication Failed 
Re-enter your username and password") I was sure, that my credentials were right but I still changed them to make sure. Since that didnt helped I created a new, clean domain and started the blank one. But I got the same problem there: Not able to login with the RIGHT credentials.

Back to my productiv domain, here is the part out of the server.log, which could cause the problem.

Any one knows what to do?

Thanks in advance

```
[2015-08-19T11:05:36.104+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-JMX-00007] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=83 _ThreadName=Thread-30] [timeMillis: 1439975136104] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config: { name = system, Protocol = rmi_jrmp, Address = XXX, Port = 8686, AcceptAll = false, AuthRealmName = admin-realm, SecurityEnabled = true} due to exception java.lang.NullPointerException]]

[2015-08-19T11:05:36.104+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=83 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1439975136104] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SecureRMIServerSocketFactory.<init>(SecureRMIServerSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.<init>(RMIConnectorStarter.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:310)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:350)]]
```

Comment: Is secure admin enabled?

Comment: Im trying to connect from localhost.

Comment: A fresh GlassFish doesn't have any password for the admin user and the admin console won't prompt for a username/password unless the password has been set/secure admin is enabled. How do you set your credentials?

Comment: Thats the weird part. When I create the domain via "asadmin" it even prompts me the "username:admin/no password" but the admin console wont log me in.

Comment: Still no Solution...

Comment: you're creating a new domain? Is there a reason you don't use domain1? It might help if you could add the process step by step so I can see what commands you're running and if anything is wrong